# AWS EC2 Ubuntu 13.04 Upgrade to Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, ubuntu-13.04

I want to upgrade my servers from Ubuntu 13.04 server to Ubuntu 13.10 server on AWS EC2.

I have 7 servers and each doing a different task. Some of the tool we use on the server are

Apache, PHP, Mysql, python, Java, syslog-ng, afick, logwatch, apt-mirror, clamav, rootkit hunter.

I just wanted to know if I "do-upgrades" will it break any of my servers.

I would not want to break any servers.

Just need your suggestions.

The reason for upgrade is Ubuntu 13.04 server has reached End of life and we need to keep our servers upgraded for compliance reasons.

Regards,
Wenceslaus Dsilva

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Someone here could tell you you'll be fine but how will they know for sure ? Surely the correct thing to do here is to test the upgrade for each of your server types. You know,

- for each $ServerType

  - Spin up a new instance configure it as per $ServerType,
  - run your test suite
  - do the upgrade
  - run test suite
  - analyze the results

Comment: Yes that Would be my goto I will try to do this. Thank you Lain

Answer (score 1):

Since you asked for suggestions - We recently faced this problem and if like me you don't want to run a OS which is not supported any more, we decided to switch to Debian all together, this might appear over kill to someone but "to each his own". Whole purpose is not to worry about OS not being supported after every 1 year. Ubuntu 13.10 is supported for 9 months only. Again, this is my personal view and you asked for suggestions.

Comment: Sure that would be something we don't need to worry too, but we are just trying to get ready for a launch and switching all servers does not seem like a good idea as we have already received compliance. Our next move would be to move to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS as it has a longer life span. Thank you for the suggestion @APZ it really appriciated